# backup wordpress database using wp-cli

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

This is a basic question..
I am trying to write a very simple script to backup my wordpress database every hour..

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This script do an hourly backup of WordPress DB

# Set global parameters
WPROOT=/home/mydomain/public_html
WPBKUPS=/usr/home/mydomain/db_backups
SITEURL=`wp option get siteurl | awk -F/ '{print $3}'`
BKNAME="$WPBKUPS/`date +%Y-%m-%d.%H%M`-$SITEURL"

# change directory
#cd $WPROOT
#cd /usr/local/www/production/httpdocs/wpsite
wp db export --allow-root - | gzip -9 > $BKNAME.sql.gz

# Stop build-up of loads of older files with exec rm \o/
find "$WPBKUPS" -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

Question 1: should I be using the option --add-drop-table?
what is the difference with my code

Question 2:
at the moment the script reside insite the wproot.. how can I change the script so that the script is not in the public facing directory?

Thank you

Comment: wp-cli only works inside the wp dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:
`--add-drop-table` it will add `Add DROP TABLE statement before each CREATE TABLE statement`.
While restoring it drops the table is already exists.

You can find more about this here [Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_add-drop-table)

Question 2:
`mysqldump –-user [user name] –-password=[password] [database name] > [dump file]`

for example:
`/usr/bin/mysqldump --user="root" --password="root"  "wp_db" > wp_db.sql`

add this command into a script file then store it outside of **WordPress** root.

Make the script executable from a terminal,

```
chmod +x /path/to/yourscript.sh
```

Open your personal crontab as

```
EDITOR=gedit crontab -e
```

and append the following line in it to run your script every hour.

```
0 */1 * * *  /path/to/yourscript.sh
```

Comment: Thank you veryu much for the inpot guys..
What about --add-drop-table

Comment: Updated the answer, If you feel its useful please upvote and accept the answer it will help others.